# How to keep RDFa attributes in MathML using MathJax

Tags: mathjax, mathml, rdfa

I've included RDFa information in MathML like so:

```
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
      <mi resource="om:Apparent_magnitude">m</mi><mo>-</mo><mi resource="om:Absolute_magnitude">M</mi>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mi>log</mi><mo> &#x2061;<!--FUNCTION APPLICATION--> </mo><mi resource="om:Distance">d</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>10</mn>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mn>10</mn><mo>-</mo><mn>5</mn><mi>log</mi><mo> &#x2061;<!--FUNCTION APPLICATION--> </mo><mi resource="om:Trigonometric_parallax">&#982;</mi>
  </math>
```

The resource attributes point to concepts in an ontology on units and measures.
When MathJax processes the MathML, I loose the RDFa information. 
The generated HTML looks like this:

```
...
<span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2">
    <span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-3" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Italic;">m</span>
    <span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-4" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Regular; padding-left: 0.25em;">−</span>
    <span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-5" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Italic; padding-left: 0.25em;">M<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.039em;"></span></span>
    <span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-6" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Regular; padding-left: 0.313em;">=</span>
...
```

But I would like it to generate (note the resource attributes):

```
...
<span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2">
    <span resource="om:Apparent_magnitude" class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-3" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Italic;">m</span>
    <span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-4" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Regular; padding-left: 0.25em;">−</span>
    <span resource="om:Absolute_magnitude" class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-5" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Italic; padding-left: 0.25em;">M<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.039em;"></span></span>
    <span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-6" style="font-family: STIXGeneral-Regular; padding-left: 0.313em;">=</span>
...
```

Is it possible to insert the RDFa attributes in the corresponding span elements generated by MathJax automatically?

Comment: FWIW I've created https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/860

Comment: Thanks, At the moment I'm trying to learn the extension mechanism to find out how I can reinsert these attributes.

Comment: It's going to be somewhat tricky since there can't be a perfectly clean mapping between internal mathml and the output. Maybe raise this on the MathJax dev list?

Comment: FYI preservation of more attributes has been implemented and will ship with the next release -- see https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/860

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thank you for the information. I'm looking forward to the new release!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no built-in way to do this. This could be realized via an extension though.